# API HttpError 400 while fetching the data from exchnage using rest api (Multi-factor authentication error)

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, adal

In my app, While fetching the data from exchange using REST Api's, I am getting this error

- **API HttpError 400 when requesting https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token for user xyz@abc
  returned
  '{"error":"interaction_required","error_description":"AADSTS50079:
  Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because
  you moved to a new location, you must enroll in multi-factor
  authentication to access **

> As I have not made any changes in my account settings still I am
>   getting an error related to MFA. So because of this, my app is getting
>   disconnected. Also some time, app is able to fetch all the events from my
>   exchange account.  What can be the possible reason for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

When did you start receiving this error?

In AAD, if you do an initial login in one location, and then login from another location, there are conditions on the AD that flag this as "risky activity".

So for your account there is a "moved to a new location" flag that can get set, automatically triggering the need for MFA.  If you do face this, check the conditional access locations in Azure and see if you can clear the flag.  (Or set up the original account with named locations in place.)